# Light distro for VM-Ware guest running under Windows

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I am forced to work under Windows but I need to access to a Linux environment for multi-platform programming tests.

I need a fully functional desktop environment, ready to use, git, emacs and classic dev' stuff, running in a virtual environment but lightweight.

*So, I want to know what are good Linux distros for virtualization?*

Comment: To run as a host or as a guest? Not that it really matters, any general-purpose distribution is equally fine for this.

Comment: Sorry for not precising, as a guest.
Tried ubuntu and fedora but the desktop env is way to heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want lightweight and maximum software compatibility, go for both [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) and [CentOS Mini](https://www.centos.org/download/) (and add the same desktop environment as Lubuntu: LXDE)

#### Why?

- Lubuntu is an official Ubuntu version, but has the lightest footprint of all of the Ubuntu versions, has great support and it uses the Debian `.deb` packaging system.
- CentOS is mostly uses as a server, but if you add the LXDE (Lightweight X11 Desktop Environment) to it, you've basically got a lightweight open and free desktop that uses the other major packaging system out there: RHEL's `.rpm`

With both, you've got maximum software compatibility testing capabilities out there, while not taking over your entire machine.

<sub>**Having said all that:** Windows is a lousy host OS and you'd be better off using one of the two above as your host and *Windows as a guest*...</sub>

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: Lubuntu sounds good, gonna try that, thanks ;)
(Don't worry for accepting, i'm from stack overflow)

Comment: @RomanGrout: favour returned!  ;-)